# How to fetch password from Alfresco UI page which has been created by admin for the new user?

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco, email, alfresco-share

I had used this code for auto generation of mails. Now the problem is password shown in the mail is the password as generated by the script. I want the **password** to be fetched from alfresco new user page, where the admin has created the password for the new user not any random string.
Below is the script that i generated for automatic mail generation.

```
if (document.isContainer && document.displayPath == "/Company Home/User Homes") {
var owner = document.properties["cm:owner"];
var pNode = people.getPerson(owner);
if (pNode!=null && pNode.exists()){

    var userName = pNode.properties.userName;
    var email = pNode.properties.email;
    var randPassword = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 30)+"-"+(Date.now());

    people.setPassword(userName, randPassword);
    logger.debug("Invitation mail: User "+userName+" password has been changed.");

    var mail = actions.create("mail");
    //mail.parameters.from = "noreply@customdomain";
    mail.parameters.to = email; 
    mail.parameters.subject = "Welcome to the site, login: "+userName+", password: "+randPassword;
    mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath("Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Invite Email Templates/invite_user_email.ftl");
    var templateModel = new Array();
    templateModel['newPassword'] = randPassword; // use ${newPassword} expression inside template
    mail.parameters.template_model = templateModel;
    mail.executeAsynchronously(document);
    logger.debug("Invitation mail has been sent to "+email);
} else {
    logger.warn("Invitation mail: User not found: "+owner);
}
}
```

Please guide me how to proceed further.

Comment: i told you the best way that you have in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080238/auto-generate-user-passwords-and-directly-sending-mail-to-respective-users-about/40081653#40081653

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-generation of email with username and random password on creation of new user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625577/auto-generation-of-email-with-username-and-random-password-on-creation-of-new-us)

Answer (score 1):

You can't decode password from its hash. You can only [encode new password and match it with hash](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html).

You can modify Alfresco Share to store raw password in custom user aspect, but this is very bad practice. Admin shouldn't know user password.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer has been posted in  Auto-generation of email with username and random password on creation of new user-- by @Imagine